# How do I preserve the form value after refresh browser?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have one simple JSP having four buttons ( Button1 , Button2 , Button3 and Button4).

The button value set  into hidden field when I click on button.

I need to get the latest button click value after refresh the page ( preserve the button value).

could anyone please help me ?

```
<script>
    function one(tab){
        document.getElementById('h').value=tab;
    }

    function fun(){
        var value =document.getElementById('h').value;
        alert(value);
    }
</script>

<td> <input type="button" name="Tab1" id="Tab1" value="Table One" onClick="one('1')"/></td>
<td> <input type="button" name="Tab2" id="Tab2" value="Table Two" onClick="one('2')"/></td>
<td> <input type="button" name="Tab3" id="Tab3" value="Table Three"onClick="one('3')"/></td>
<td> <input type="button" name="Tab4" id="Tab4" value="Table four" onClick="fun()"/></td>

<input type="hidden" name="h" id="h"  value=""/>
```

Comment: In the scenario you're working on, are you concerned with a programmatically triggered refresh or a user clicking the browser's refresh button?

Answer (score 4):

You might try using cookies, for example:

```
function one(tab){
    createCookie("savedvar",tab,1);
}
```

and then accessing it by: `readCookie("savedvar")`

Using the code from: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not accessing the cookie. My idea is to get the button value which is clicked before page refresh.

Comment: Thanks, I implement the same logic . Working fine -

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple library to save form variables.  It aims to automatically save them so you don't need to worry about setting and getting individual values.  Here is the code:
  https://gist.github.com/zaus/4717416

There is also a more comprehensive library here:

https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Garlic.js

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to accomplish this. You don't want to use a cookie because a cookie is shared across browser tabs.

> sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated,** which differs from how session cookies work.